# how to get key of a value that in array of array?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I can't deal with this. Please help me. This is array:

```
$arr = array("data" => array(
                    array("id" => "5451"),
                    array("id" => "45346346")
                    ));
```

for example how can i find the key for id `45346346` ?

```
$key = array_search($arr['data'], 45346346);
```

I have tried this but its not working.

I'm trying to delete that array line. I'm guessing I can do that with unset($key)

Comment: What answer are you expecting for `45346346`?

Comment: What do you want? `id`? `data`? Something else?

Comment: I have to delete that line with a php function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of array of arrays.  `$arr['data']` is an array with 2 values.  These values are both arrays.  `array_search` doesn't work, as `45346346` doesn't match an array.

You'd have you cook your own search, something like this:

```
function find_in_array($arr, $val){
   $found = false;
   foreach($arr as $k=>$x){
      if(array_search($val, $x) !== FALSE){
         $found = $k;
         break;
      }
   }
   return $found;
}
```

Then you can do: `$key = find_in_array($arr['data'], 45346346);`.  This will return 1, the index of the array containing `'id' => 45346346` inside `$arr['data']`.

DEMO: http://codepad.org/pSxaBT9g